# Django equivalent of sub query

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to ask if there is a different way to the following raw SQL query

**SQL query**

```
SELECT id,
       title,
       date_format(books.timestamp,"%%Y/%%m/%%d") AS timestamp,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pages WHERE pages.book_id=books.id) AS page_count
FROM books
ORDER BY books.timestamp DESC LIMIT %s
```

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title     = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Page(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    book      = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def something(request):
    n_books = 10
    books = Book.objects.raw(the_query, [n_books])
    return render(request, "books/list.html", {"books":books})
```

I thought I could do this by using filter() but I don't know how to handle the sub query.
Is there any Django equivalent way that uses only Python codes? Or is it better to use a raw SQL query?

Thanks to @dostogircse171, tried a similar one on the shell:

```
In [1]: from django.db.models import F
In [2]: from book.models import Book
In [3]: Book.objects.annotate(t=F("timestamp")).values("t")
Out[3]: <QuerySet [{'t': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 5, 15, 58, 21, 114352)}, {'t': 
datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 5, 16, 2, 48, 916458)}]>
In [4]: Book.objects.annotate(t=F("timestamp").strftime("%Y")).values("t")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6a25525e5bb4> in <module>
----> 1 Book.objects.annotate(t=F("timestamp").strftime("%Y")).values("t")
AttributeError: 'F' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result using Django ORM without using a raw SQL query for your project.

```
from django.db.models import Count, F
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Book

def book_list(request):
    n_books = 10
    books = Book.objects.annotate(page_count=Count('page')).annotate(
        timestamp_formatted=F('timestamp').strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    ).order_by('-timestamp').values('id', 'title','timestamp_formatted','page_count')[:n_books]
    return render(request, 'books/list.html', {'books': books})
```

Please note the 3 new modules I imported Count, F & timezone. You need to add these as your query has a timestamp and count functions and we used these functions to fetch and format data.

Try to render this code provided above and see what output you get and if this works for you. You can use python shell to test this if you feel comfortable. But make sure to import count & timezone modules before running on the shell.

Updated code (without using F class):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Func, Value, CharField
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Book

def book_list(request):
    n_books = 10
    books = Book.objects.annotate(
        page_count=Count('page'),
        timestamp_formatted=Func(
            Cast('timestamp', output_field=CharField()),
            Value('YYYY/MM/DD'),
            function='to_char',
        ),
    ).order_by('-timestamp').values('id', 'title', 'timestamp_formatted', 'page_count')[:n_books]
    return render(request, 'books/list.html', {'books': books})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The code works great if I remove **.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')** part. With the part, I get **'F' object has no attribute 'strftime'** error.

Comment: Got it. I think it's due to importing F module. Can you try adding this "from django.db.models import F" and test if this works fine with the issue with strfime function?

Comment: Thank you again. I added it but it did not work. I also tried a shorter one in the shell mode but it did not work either.

Comment: @Jihyun I have updated my answer at the bottom with a new code can you try that. This is without using F class.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much again. It is working. I added  **from django.db.models.functions import Cast** and replaced **to_char** to **date_format** (to_char did not work for MySQL)